# Jenkins Pipeline continue latest build at certain time

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline which runs per commit, does a build and runs some sanity tests.
Then at 8pm I want the latest successful build to carry on and run more indepth tests as part of the same pipeline.

I have looked at milestone and lock but it seem that the first commit of the day would grab the lock to wait till 8pm and then be "promoted" and then when that finished it would run the latest which doesnt work for me.

I have looked at milestone and then having a user-input to hold all the builds at the end of the first stage, but that would mean manually clicking a job at 8pm or having and external script to do it.

I've also looked at checkpoint and this doesnt appear to have the ability to do what I need either.

Can anyone suggest a groovy method for a new build to supersede an old one or plugin that would work for me?

Comment: can you provide your pipeline script that grabbed the first and then the last build of the day? maybe it s more clear then what may be missing. I am looking for a similar solution too but haven't had the time to have a deeper look into it.

Comment: Hello. Ended up writing a Jenkins plugin to do what I needed as I couldn't find anything else that met my needs https://github.com/leth/jenkins-pipeline-scheduledgate-plugin. It allows you to add a cron before a stage and only when the cron is met will the latest build continue. If there is a build waiting for the cron and a newer build gets there the original build will be stopped as superseded.

Comment: Is Your plugin still available somewhere ?